# @SpringBootApplication Annotation not finding beans in classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

From my understanding using `@SpringBootApplication` is the equivalent of having `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`. For this reason I can't understand why Spring isn't finding my annotations. As far as I'm aware the project structure is as it should be and everything is annotated properly. However when I visit the mapped endpoint `http://localhost:8080/dashboard` or `http://localhost:8080/dashboard/`, I see a 404 error.

I just created a new Spring Boot project using IntelliJ's built in Spring Initialiser, I selected Spring Web, and a few components for Postgres. Inside the project I can't find any additional .xml files for configuration. However, I did find:

`DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java - which hasn't been edited`

`ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration.java - which hasn't been edited`

### Structure of my project is as follows:

```
com
+-abcde
  +-appname
    +-controllers
        DashboardController.java
      Application.java
```

### Application.java:

```
package com.abcde.appname;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

### DashboardController.java

```
package com.abcde.appname.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public class DashboardController {

    @Autowired
    public DashboardController() {

    }

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView renderDashboard() {
        return new ModelAndView("dashboard/index");
    }

}
```

Alongside these files I also have the following,

### application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.main.banner-mode=off
```

### build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.abcde'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '14'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

### stacktrace

```
2020-09-09 23:24:46.053  INFO 57966 --- [           main] c.d.f.Application          : Starting Application on OP-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 57966 (/Users/op/IdeaProjects/lalala/build/classes/java/main started by op in /Users/op/IdeaProjects/lalala)
2020-09-09 23:24:46.054  INFO 57966 --- [           main] c.d.f.Application          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-09 23:24:46.374  INFO 57966 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-09-09 23:24:46.388  INFO 57966 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-09-09 23:24:46.716  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-09-09 23:24:46.720  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-09 23:24:46.720  INFO 57966 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-09-09 23:24:46.775  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-09 23:24:46.775  INFO 57966 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 700 ms
2020-09-09 23:24:46.832  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 6.4.4 by Redgate
2020-09-09 23:24:46.835  INFO 57966 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-09 23:24:46.872  INFO 57966 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-09-09 23:24:46.879  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres (PostgreSQL 12.3)
2020-09-09 23:24:46.901  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.011s)
2020-09-09 23:24:46.905  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "public": 10
2020-09-09 23:24:46.905  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
2020-09-09 23:24:46.960  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-09 23:24:46.985  INFO 57966 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-09-09 23:24:47.000  WARN 57966 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-09-09 23:24:47.010  INFO 57966 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
2020-09-09 23:24:47.070  INFO 57966 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-09-09 23:24:47.122  INFO 57966 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2020-09-09 23:24:47.253  INFO 57966 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-09-09 23:24:47.257  INFO 57966 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-09-09 23:24:47.264  INFO 57966 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-09-09 23:24:47.265  INFO 57966 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-09-09 23:24:47.266  INFO 57966 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-09-09 23:24:47.273  INFO 57966 --- [           main] c.d.f.lalala          : Started Application in 1.401 seconds (JVM running for 1.885)
2020-09-09 23:24:49.520  INFO 57966 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-09 23:24:49.520  INFO 57966 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-09 23:24:49.524  INFO 57966 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
```

Any insight into this problem would be much appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Does the app start without error?  Is there a stack trace?  Try debugging and break on the controller method.  Perhaps `dashboard/index` is not found.

Comment: No error is being thrown in the stack trace, i'll edit the post to show the contents of it. I tried setting a breakpoint inside the mapped method and it doesn't get activated

Comment: Where is `dashboard/index` resource in your project? Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it's in src/main/resources/templates/dashboard/index.ftl and it's a simple file which contains just a <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably successfully invoking the renderDashboard() and is not finding "dashboard/index". You can verify that by debugging and setting a breakpoint or adding a log/System.out println statement. Does your index file exist and is it setup correctly?

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. Thank you, I wasn't aware that a freemarker error would show as a 404, I was expecting a 500